# How can i send a webcal request with node.js?

Tags: node.js, protocols, icalendar, webcal

I try to parse an icloud calendar (CalDav). The calendar is accessible via webcal-protocol. The address of the calendar looks like `webcal://p19-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/....`

So my (hopefully easy) question is: How can i send a request with the webcal-protocol? I tried it with the request module, but got that error message `[Error: Invalid protocol: webcal:]` Also the nativ http-module seems not suitable for that.

**Edit:**
My try with the http-module:
var url = "webcal://p19-calendarws.icloud.com/ca/**************";

```
var http = require('http');
    http.get(url, function(res) {
      console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
    });
```

Get following error: `Error: Protocol:webcal: not supported.`

**The Solution:**
First i have to replace the `webcal://` with `https://` in the calendar address. Apple will redirect to an icalendar file of the calendar. Because of the redirect i use the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module, which handles redirects very well.

```
var request = require('request');
    var calendarUrl = 'webcal://p19-calendarws.icloud.com/*****';

    var options = {
      url: calendarUrl.replace('webcal://', 'https://'),
      gzip: true
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, icalData) {
      console.log(icalData);
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried reading it with plain http(s)? The only other alternative would be [this](https://github.com/mikedeboer/jsDAV).

Comment: Yes i tried the https module, it doesnt work. The library, you posted, is a WebDav server. But i need an CalDav client, that work with the webcal protocol.

Comment: Sounds like an opportunity to write an NPM module.

Comment: @tschiela It has a CalDav client, which is currently in development. So it may or may not work. https://github.com/mikedeboer/jsDAV/tree/master/lib/CalDAV

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince, what would be the right way to start with? I thought about to use the net-module.

Comment: @BenFortune, i cant find the part where the request will be fired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebCal is just http. All you have to do is to replace the scheme.

The reason a different scheme was used, was so that browsers are able to easily use a different application to handle the request, but it's 100% a single HTTP request, and a `GET`. It's not DAV.

Comment: But how i can fire the request in node? Please see me edit above.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer brought me to the solution. Not directly but helped me alot.

Comment: I made the assumption in my answer that you knew how to do a http request ;). Make sure you replace webcal to http, and webcals to https.